# Differential Equations which involve Infinite Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem statement is as follows:
Find the general solution for the following equation for $x(t)$.

$$x''+ 9x = 2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(nt)/n^3$$

I can't find anything about this in my differential equations book; however it seems like a simple case of the linearity of solutions. Please do not feel like you must check the Algebra, etc but rather if the method of solving is correct.

I will present my methodology of solving the problem; and would kindly ask if someone could tell me if I am correct as I have no solution provided.

First I solve for the complementary solution of:

$$x''+9x=0$$

whose solution is:
$x_c = C_1\cos(3t)+C_2\sin(3t)$

I proceed to solve for the particular solution corresponding to the constant 2:
$x_{p0}=A_0$ thus $9A=2$, and $A=2/9$.

Next I solve for the n-th particular solution corresponding to $\cos(nt)$ keeping in mind the duplicity at $n=3$.
$x_{pn}=A_n\cos(nt)+B_n\sin(nt)$ from which it follows that the second derivative is:
$x_{pn}''=-n^2A_n\cos(nt)-n^2B_n\sin(nt)$

thus for the nth particular solution the differential equation is:
$-n^2A_n\cos(nt)-n^2B_n\sin(nt)+9(A_n\cos(nt)+B_n\sin(nt))=\cos(nt)/n^3$

it is obvious that $B_n$ should be zero since no $\sin(nt)$ exist on the right side; furthermore,
$-n^2A_n+9A_n=1/n^3$ thus $A_n=\frac 1{(9-n^2)n^3}$

for the case of n=3 the particular solution takes the form:
$x_{p3}=tA_3\cos(3t)+tB_3\sin(3t)$
then:
$x_{p3}''=\cos(3t)(6B_3-9tA_3)+\sin(3t)(-6A_3-9tB_3)$

putting this into the differential equation yields:
$$\cos(3t)(6B_3-9tA_3)+\sin(3t)(-6A_3-9tB_3)+9(\cos(3t)A_3+\sin(3t)B_3)=\frac{\cos(3t)}{n^3}$$

Again equating coefficients yields: $B_3=0$ and $A_3=1/162$

hence would the solution be:
$x=C_1\cos(3t)+C_2\sin(3t) + 2/9 + \frac {t\cos3t} {162} + \sum_{n=1,n \neq 3}^ \infty \frac {\cos(nt)} {(9-n^2)n^3}$?

Comment: To check your answer, differentiate and see what you get.

Comment: I think that you forgot the fact that the rhs of the differential equation contains $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(nt)/n^3$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? i differentiated termwise the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(nt)/n^3$